# spring-boot and mockito test - why is my test failing?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

In the application I'm working now, I need to implement a few tests and build upon them. I've been reading and trying out a few things, but haven't had much success.

The goal is to start back-filling with tests the service layer of the application. The first one to be covered is `UserService`.

So, my idea is to assert the test user we use on the application returns itself. The test class so far is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ApplicationMain.class})
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    CentralData dataProviderMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    private <project>User testUser;
    private <project>User mockUser;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(CentralData.class);
        System.out.println("dataProviderMock: " + dataProviderMock);
        System.out.println("userService: " + userService);
        userService = new UserService(dataProviderMock);
        testUser = createTestUser();
    }

    private <project>User createTestUser() {
        testUser = new <project>User();
        testUser.setSystemId("testuser");
        testUser.setEmailAddress("testuser@system.com");
        testUser.setFirstName("Test");
        testUser.setLastName("User");
        // save user
        userService.save(testUser);
        return testUser;
    }

    @Test
    public void whenUserIdIsProvided_thenRetrievedNameIsCorrect() {
        mockUser = userService.getUserById("testuser");
        when(userService.getUser("testuser")).thenReturn(testUser);
        assertEquals(testUser, mockUser);
    }
}
```

On my `UserService`, I have this:

```
public UserService(CentralData dataProvider) {
    this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
}
```

When I save the user, the mocked `dataProviderMock` logs to the console what I expect it to log. But on the test itself, the `mockUser` is always null.

I understand the `userService` does not really accesses the data layer and the database, so `mockUser` being null is not really wrong. So, how could I perform this test?

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something quite basic here, but can't really see it.

Comment: you want to get the user from database and check against User object? so there's no mocking, no?

Comment: remove MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(CentralData.class); from your setup method. I just wrote an answer for the similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271406/3295987